# How to disable button in RecyclerView and from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, button, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I am trying to disable button after click in RecyclerView from Retrofit response.

Application is using RecyclerView to populate list and I am using Retrofit to communicate to back-end REST API. There are two buttons inside one item and Retrofit client is activated on click. And if response from API is successful button should be disabled. I came across on two problems:
first few items works just fine, but after few scrolls buttons I have never clicked on are disabled also;
second was that little few random buttons further on in list are still clickable.

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.btnPositive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//              init Retrofit Client
                JSONPlaceHolderAPI mAPIService;
                mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIServiceFetch();
                mAPIService.getNews(url).enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> 
                                           response) {
                            holder.btnPositive.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
//                      do code
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        holder.btnNegative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                JSONPlaceHolderAPI mAPIService;
                mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIServiceFetch();
                mAPIService.getNews(url).enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> 
                                           response) {
                            holder.btnNegative.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                    // do code
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

I suppose problem is somewhere in Retrofit where it uses background threads or AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens as the recycler view recycles(as the name suggests) the view that is visible to you and gives the same set of ids to every set of items which causes this problem .

This problem has 2 solution :

1) Stop the recycle behaviour of recyclerview as follows:-

```
     @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    myViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
}
```

But i strongly deny to use this cause recycling is reason why we use recyclerview.

2) Using a POJO Class:-

The best solution for it is to use a POJO class which will have two variables the first one is value and the second one is a boolean variable which show is the item disabled or not . Set the value of POJO boolean variable to true for the items u want to disable and in onBindViewHolder method only disable the buttons for the items which has false set in boolean variable .

If you still are confused contact me i will send you an example of it .

Comment: I am not that confused anymore, but i would like to see example. Of course first solution is not an option. Which method would be better, to make list as @faranjit said or to make POJO class? It seems to me that it's same thing.

Comment: Yea both are same but creating a POJO is a better choice as u can always move a POJO arraylist(Make the POJO class Serializable or Parcelable) with all the data between activities while maintaining other arraylist will be more tiresome work . If you feel the answer is correct then upvote and Mark it as correct @IvanZ.

Comment: May I see an example? Thanks. :)

Comment: Will post a link soon

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvceoMt7FbgGad2MWJVuGfY6iSM?e=2K37nI
This is the link for the project enjoy and feel free to contact me @ shahaashit26@gmail.com . And upvote and mark as correct the answers you feel are right for the community . Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Is this aplicable to the button animations?

Comment: Animations for what ?

Comment: For button, after click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold states of those buttons. You can hold states in items(such as `isNegativeEnabled`, `willPositiveDisplay` etc.) of the list that populates recyclerview. When you click positive button, change `willPositiveDisplay` to false.

```
list[position].willPositiveDisplay = false;
```

And check `list[position].willPositiveDisplay` is true set visibility as visible, if not set as gone. And do this for negative button.