# Problem while disabling button after click in RecyclerView items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, state

I want to disable two buttons from certain item in RecyclerView after click. I have implemented code from:
[How to disable button in RecyclerView and from AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397181/how-to-disable-button-in-recyclerview-and-from-asynctask/57397632?noredirect=1#comment101305888_57397632)

I have added boolean to hold state of button (isClicked) in POJO class which I update after click.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NewsViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if(Fragment.List.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).isTrueBtnClicked){
            holder.btnPositive.setEnabled(false);
            holder.btnPositive.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkGray);
            holder.btnNegative.setEnabled(false);
            holder.btnNegative.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkGray);

        }else{
            //to do
        }
        //used position instead getAdapterPosition()
        if(BlicFragment.List.get(position).isLieBtnClicked){

            holder.btnPositive.setEnabled(false);
            holder.btnPositive.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkGray);
            holder.btnNegative.setEnabled(false);
            holder.btnNegative.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkGray);

        }else{
            //holder.btnPositive.setEnabled(false);
        }


        holder.btnPositive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //SendPost postingToDb = new SendPost();
                //postingToDb.sendPost(sTitle, sDesc, url, sDate, sImgUrl[0], 1, 0, "Blic");
                JSONPlaceHolderAPI mAPIService;
                mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIServiceFetch();
                mAPIService.getNews(url).enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                        if(response.body().getSuccess()==1){
                            isPositiveBtnClicked(holder);
                        }else{
                            isPositiveBtnClicked(holder);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

and method

```
private void isPositiveBtnClicked(NewsViewHolder holder){
        Fragment.List.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setTrueBtnClicked(!Fragment.List.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).isTrueBtnClicked);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.e("clicked positive button", String.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
    }
```

I am facing that button becomes disabled, and next five buttons are unaffected. But every sixth button from the clicked one is getting disabled. Eventually all others are disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is happening because Recylerview always reuses or render view that comes in screen from that goes out from screen.so make sure you should be perfectly  resting view to normal like in some condition view's are changing to enable state using some `if()`condition then there must be `else` part for making them disable.
In your case for example...

```
        if(Fragment.List.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).isTrueBtnClicked){
            holder.btnPositive.setEnabled(false);
            holder.btnPositive.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkGray);
            holder.btnNegative.setEnabled(false);
            holder.btnNegative.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkGray);

        }else{
            holder.btnPositive.setEnabled(true);
            holder.btnPositive.setBackgroundResource(R.color.greenEnable);
            holder.btnNegative.setEnabled(true);
            holder.btnNegative.setBackgroundResource(R.color.greenEnable);
        }
```

Comment: This solves problem. What about animation? After I animate button onClick every time when its in the View, animation triggers again?

Comment: Sorry, What animation you doing and where?

Comment: I want to animate those buttons on click.